# Are std::signal and std::raise thread-safe?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, c++11, signals

The C and C++ standards support the concept of signal. However, the C11 standard says that the function signal() cannot be called in multi-threaded environments, or the behavior is undefined. But I think the signal mechanism is by nature for multi-threaded environments.

A quote from the C11 standard 7.14.1.1.7

> "Use of this function in a multi-threaded program results in undefined behavior. The
>   implementation shall behave as if no library function calls the signal function."

Any explanations about this?

The following code is self-evident.

```
#include <thread>
#include <csignal>

using namespace std;

void SignalHandler(int)
{
    // Which thread context here?
}

void f()
{
    //
    // Running in another thread context.
    //
    raise(SIGINT); // Is this call safe?
}

int main()
{
    //
    // Register the signal handler in main thread context.
    //
    signal(SIGINT, SignalHandler);

    thread(f).join();
}
```

Comment: Signalling was originally intended for interprocess communication (IPC). In POSIX, signal support in multithreaded apps was mostly an afterthought, and a lot of threading stuff gets really evil in the presence of async signals.

Comment: It is not required to be, as the standard says.

Comment: Besides, why would you really need this? You have much more straightforward ways of communicating within a multithreaded app besides signaling yourself.

Comment: It's standard, I like standard-provided functions if any better than system-provided ones.

Comment: I recommend that if you want to send signals to different threads of the same program you look into the pthread library, although I tend to agree with @millimoose that there are easier ways to communicate things among threads, such as semaphores, shared data, etc.

Comment: I'm working under Windows, so Linux-specific techniques are not useful for me.

Comment: @xmllmx Semaphores are in no way Linux-specific techniques. I'm barely aware `<thread>` exists, it might be worth looking into it for synchronisation utilities. (If it doesn't have them it flat out might not be appropriate for your app, regardless of how much you want to restrict yourself to "pure" C++.)

Comment: @millimoose: But if i want just to set custom signal handler in multithreaded programm. Not for interthread communication. In such a case will there be UB?

Comment: @A.Mikhaylov Isn't that **exactly** what the standard quote in the OP's question says? *Undefined behaviour* means that, for example, you don't know if a signal handler will interrupt *all* the threads, or if it will be executed on the *currently* executing thread, or on some predictable thread like the one that set the handler. If the latter, does this preempt the other threads or wait its turn? This is just the tip of the iceberg when it comes to things you have to consider to *extend the defined behaviour* of those functions for multithreading. The C++ standard just decided to not even try.

Comment: @A.Mikhaylov What that means it that whether the implementation does something sensible (whatever that means in your case) or if it just takes the naïve approach is not guaranteed - you just can't know (without considering the implementation specifics - i.e. what threading library is used by `<thread>` and what it does in the face of signals) what state the rest of the program will be in your signal handler. As an example, POSIX.1 has process-directed signals which may be handled by an arbitrarily selected thread in the process, but Linux thread libraries may be slightly nonconforming to POSIX

Comment: @millimoose: I conclude from your explanation that there is no portable way to set custom signal handler in multithreaded program. And apparently this is reasonable behavior, thnx.

Comment: @A.Mikhaylov See also my comments to one of the answers below, I might have gone over this before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> But I think the signal mechanism is by nature for multi-threaded environments.

I think this sentence is the central misunderstanding. `signal()` is a method for inter-*process* communication, not for inter-*thread*. Threads share common memory and can therefore communicate via mutexes and control structures. Processes don't have common memory and must make-do with some explicit communication structures like `signal()` or the filesystem.

Comment: If one process registered a signal handler, and another process called raise; can the first process' signal handler receive the signal?

Comment: @xmllmx: Undefined by the standard. On Linux, yes. However, when doing stuff Linux-specifically, just use pthread.

Comment: Are these functions outdated and useless today? Do the standards support them only for backward compatible?

Comment: @xmllmx: `signal` is superseded by `sigaction`, but the functions themselves are perfectly OK. They are just not meant for multi-threaded programs.

Comment: I'm working under Windows, so Linux-specific techniques are not useful for me.

Comment: @xmllmx Signals as defined in C aren't particularly useful for anything. It requires additional implementation defined guarantees, such as that certain library functions may be called in a handler, to make them useful. Windows doesn't support much, if anything, beyond what's required by the standard. Instead Windows has it's own platform specific methods for inter-process communication. For inter-thread communication the C++11 thread library is supported on Windows, so you can write portable, standard conforming code for inter-thread communication.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confusing signaling, which is process specific, with communication between threads. If it is sharing information between threads that you're after, you will probably find what you want in the new [C++11 thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). Of course, it depends on what you really want to do.

From what I can tell of your code, you want a thread to "signal" an event in some way and you want to be able to run some code when that event is signalled. Given that, I'd take a closer look at the Futures section in the thread support library.

Comment: I can understand and use thread, future, promise, etc. I just wan to know why rather than how.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I would then ask, what you mean by safe - Are you asking whether other threads will be interrupted? Are you asking whether multiple threads can enter the signal handler?

Comment: @xmllmx Why? Because those are the tools intended for the task of getting threads to cooperate, when `signal()` isn't as the documentation flat you tells you to. As in, nobody bothered to define any useful properties it would have for this situation. (Like that a signal handler will be executed on the thread that defined it, or whatever.) You're asking why you shouldn't use a hammer to dice vegetables. Sure if you pound at it you'll end up with smaller pieces of vegetables but it's hardly the approach you'd want to take.

Comment: @millimoose, +1 for your explanations. I think this is because under Windows, there are few people use these functions.

Comment: @xmllmx MSDN also tells me support for `<thread>`, `<mutex>`, and probably whatever other header files are related to this C++ feature is new in VS2012, so that would also explain things.

Answer (score 2):

The C11 standard's statement that "Use of this function in a multi-threaded program results in undefined behavior," refers specifically to the function `signal()`. So the question is if the use of `signal()` is done "in a multi-threaded program."

The term 'multi-threaded program' isn't defined in the C standard as far as I can tell, but I would take it to mean a program in which multiple threads of execution have been created and have not completed. That would mean that at the time `signal()` is called in your example program the program is not multi-threaded and therefore the program's behavior is not undefined under this requirement.

(However C++11 requires that "All signal handlers shall have C linkage," *[18.10 Other runtime support [support.runtime] p9]*. Since your example program uses a handler with C++ linkage the behavior is undefined.)

---

As others have pointed out signals aren't intended for communication between threads. For example the C and C++ standards don't even specify what thread they run on. The standard library instead provides other tools for inter-thread communcation, such as mutexes, atomics, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just misintrepret the term *undefined behavior*, which is unfortunately much overloaded to mean "bad things will happen". Here the term really just means what it says: the C standard doesn't make any assumption about what it means to use `signal` in a multi-threaded context.

In general the `signal`/`raise` interface in the C standard is not very useful by itself, but only a placeholder for platform/OS specific things that are defined on top of it.

So for an interaction between `signal` and threats doesn't give you a contract. Or stated otherwise, the interaction of `signal` and threads is left to the platform
implementation.