# Is there a C++ standard library wrapper around or replacement for pthread_sigmask?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, c++11, signals

In the code base I am working on, all thread control is done using `std::thread` and related objects, rather than using `pthread` directly.

However, I have not been able to find a C++ equivalent of `pthread_sigmask`, so I am wondering if there is a standard C++ way to block signals, and thereby handle signals consistently in a multi-threaded application.

In particular, I am wondering if there is a way to do the example [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/pthread_sigmask.html) using `c++11` without  `#include <pthread.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

The `pthread_sigmask` is a pthread function, and the C++ standard library of thread functions doesn't rely on a specific threading library. For example, a Windows implementation is likely to use the Windows APIs under the hood.

If you want to use that function, you'll need to include `<signal.h>` and use it directly. Even [examples from Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server4/posix_main.cpp) do this.

Consider what you're trying to do, and ask yourself whether you really want to break portability by relying on a non-standard function or concept. Remember, threads and signals might not play nicely together; see [Are std::signal and std::raise thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613409/are-stdsignal-and-stdraise-thread-safe)