# Usage of std::signal in term of multi-threaded programming in C++11

Tags: c++, signals, std

In the question [are std::signal and std::raise thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613409/are-stdsignal-and-stdraise-thread-safe) are there some comments to differentiate communication of inter-process from that of multi-threads. I'd like assent on opinion that `signal` be used only in case of IPC by its nature. However, developers always need to set signals for their programs, no matter if they decide IPC or multi-threaded paradigm to apply afterwards, as to handle signals that OS raises.

So my question is about what shall developers do to handle signals in that case - that is, for example, we'd like a multi-threaded program exit upon signal arises. ("Talk is cheap, show me the code")

```
//C++11 standard conformance

#include <csignal>
#include <thread>

void function(){
    //some a loop
    while(/* predicate to exit */)
    {
        //...
    }
}

//we might wish to flag a volatile variable in the following handler for asynchronous thread of this program to judge on to exit. But it's not certainly that thread of handler rather than function blocks on these signals! (O.o)

void handler(int signal){
    switch(signal){
        case SIGINT: //...upon interruption
        case SIGTERM: //...upon termination
        case SIGQUIT: //...upon quit
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    std::signal(SIGINT, handler);

    std::future<void> result=std::async(std::launch::async, function);

    return 0;
}
```

The framework may be self-explanatory to you. Shall I presume that it's always the thread of handler rather than function to block on signal? What shall I do to terminate this program in general?